# Does enabling more IIS logging fields consume resources?

Tags: windows, iis-7, logging, memory, central-processing-unit

It seems that IIS7 doesn't enable the bytes sent and bytes received fields in its logs by default.

I would like to enable them so I could watch bandwidth consumption of individual sites, but my server is short on resources and barely able to keep up as it stands. Would this affect memory consumption negatively? How about CPU usage? Or any kind of performance overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you'd feel it in memory or CPU. You might feel it in Disk I/O, tough, as you will be writing perhaps 2-3% more to disk for every request.

So if your Disk I/O is extremely limited, you may have a problem, otherwise you should be home free.